# Do I need a Schengen Visa if I have Entry Clearance to the UK under Tier 2

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, europe

I'm a Turkish citizen and do I need to have a Schengen Visa for short visits to countries which are inside the Schengen Area If I have Entry Clearance to the UK under Tier 2? I wasn't able to find where can I check this information.

Comment: Your nationality?

Comment: @GayotFow sorry, updated the question.

Comment: Note that the UK is not in Schengen.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know but AFAIK, UK citizen doesn't need Schengen visa for short visits. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @tugberk That's true but your question says you're a Turkish citizen. The fact that you have a visa to enter the UK doesn't mean you're treated as a British citizen for countries you visit from the UK.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know that I am not a British citizen. The point of the question is whether Tier-2 visa holders have the same rights for the Schengen area or not. The question has been already answered.

Comment: @tugberk I don't think having a visa for one country ever gives you extra rights to visit some other country, does it? If there are cases where it does, they're very much the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A T2 entry clearance (or colloquially, visa) is not recognized outside of the UK.  Instead, the person's nationality is used as the determining factor.  You wrote that you are Turkish...

Turkish nationals are listed in the **EU Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001** as requiring a visa to enter the Schengen zone. See http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2001R0539:20091219:EN:PDF for the details.

In the more general sense, the same principle holds true for all UK visas.  There's http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:336:0001:0003:EN:PDF which has this to say about mutuality and reciprocity....

> This Regulation constitutes a development of the provisions of the
>   Schengen acquis in which the United Kingdom does not take part, in
>   accordance with Council Decision 2000/365/EC of 29 May 2000 concerning
>   the request by the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern
>   Ireland to take part in some of the provisions of the Schengen acquis
>   (4). The United Kingdom is therefore not taking part in its adoption
>   and is not bound by it or subject to its application.